# Is $f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(m,n)=m+n$ onto?

Tags: functions, proof-verification

**1) Scratch**

Let$f(m,n)=y$ and $m=0$ , $n=1$ then $n=y, $ so I will use the pair $(0,y)$.

**2) Proof**

Take any $y\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $(0,y)\in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ and $f(0,y)=0+y=y$. Therebefore $f$ is onto.

Is  correct my proof? Is there a better proof?

Comment: What is $f$? Is it a function $f:\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$?

Comment: Well, you need to clarify what $f$ is defined on.  The header says $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$ but your argument refers to $\mathbb Z$.  Once you clear that up you should be good.

Comment: It does mater where $f$ is define $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb Z$ the result similar. and the OP proof is correct

Comment: If $f:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z} $ given by $f(m,n)=5m+4n$ $ what should be the scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct, although I do not see the need for a scratch of yours, which doesn´t quite make sense. I do not see any "better" or simpler proof because you have very easily shown that every value from $\mathbb R$ is attained by your function.

You could, for example, take any $m$ you want and define $n$ to be $n=y-m$. Then you would also have $f(m,n)=y$, so that would show you that there are a lot of values that are transformed into some arbitrary single $y$ so that your function is not an injection, but that is not what is being asked here.

If you are interested in the case $f(m,n)=5m+4n$ then from $5m+4n=y$ it follows $n=\dfrac{y-5m}{4}$ so you have $f(m,\dfrac{y-5m}{4})=5m+4 \cdot \dfrac{y-5m}{4}=y$.

This just tells you that your $f(m,n)=am+bn$ will transform straight lines into single numbers.

This is all if we talk over $\mathbb R^2$, but over $\mathbb Z^2$ there are some divisibility criteria that are crucial to know what can and what can not be obtained and why it can be obtained an infinite number of times.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer was very helpful for me :)

Comment: @Daniel The most important thing is that it is clearer to you now.